# Can I change the name of an export in es6 module?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm using es6 and therefore don't have class decorators.  If I had class decorators I would do this:

```
@b
export class A {}
```

which would mean b(A) would be exported as A

However I don't have decorators so I have to do something like this:

```
class A {}
export const C = b(A)
```

but now my module exports b(A) as C but I want it to be exported as A.

Is there a way to change the name as I'm exporting to make this work?

Comment: Why not just `export const A = b(class {…});`?

Comment: ES6 doesn't have decorators whether it's strict or not, whatever that means.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can choose a different name using `export { ... }` syntax.

```
class A {}
const C = b(A)
export {C as A};
```

You could also potentially do

```
export const A = b(class A { });
```